# Taylor Polynom inequality

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

So the question is like this: Given $f(x)=\cos x$,
find the taylor Polynomial of degree 2 and 4 and prove:

$$P_2(x) < f(x) < P_4(x).$$

so I calculated these two polynomials:

$$P_2(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}$$

$$P_4(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4!}$$

and I know this:

$$\cos x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

I'm having trouble combining all this information to prove the inequality, any help is appreciated!

EDIT: the inequality holds for $x\neq 0$.

Comment: For each fixed $x$, the series is alternating.

Comment: I know that... how does it help me prove the inequality?

Comment: one underestimates the fuction and the other overestimates it

Comment: do you mind providing a formal proof?

Comment: Do you know the remainder/error of a taylor polynomial? it should have been taught in class

Comment: Yes I know but for f(x)=cosx the remainder approaches zero as n approaches infinity.

Comment: you don't have to look at the remainder as n approaches infinity, only the values for the question. edit: in particular, for the 2nd and 4th remainder term, is r(x) greater or less than 0?

Comment: I'm a bit confused... can you please write it all down?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$R_n(x) = \frac{f^{(n + 1)}(z)(x - a)^{(n + 1)}}{(n + 1)!}$, where $z$ is in $0 < z < a$.

If $R_n(x) > 0$, then the polynomial gives an underestimate; if $R_n(x) < 0$ then the polynomial gives an overestimate.

Comment: a is part of the question. they ask to develop the taylor expansion around 0. and z is in min(0,x)<z<max(0,x) . the remainder can be either positive or negative depends on X.

Comment: what about for values of x close to 0?

Comment: then R4(x)>0 and R2(x)<0. but how does it help me prove it? the remainder isn't part of the inequality only the taylor series.

Comment: Keep in mind that the exact taylor series are the polynomials listed above plus the remainder term

Comment: I would love it if you could write everything clearly.

Answer (score 1):

By the Leibniz test, if $(a_n)$ is monotonically decreasing towards zero, then the series $S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k a_k$ converges and the partial sums are alternatingly smaller and larger than the limit,

$$s_{2m+1}\le S\le s_{2n}.$$

Now check for which values of $x$ the sequence of the $a_n(x)=\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ is decreasing.

---

Note that for the estimates of the question, one can apply the above argument to the series for $1-\cos(x)$, i.e., $a_n(x)=\frac{x^{2(n+1)}}{(2(n+1))!}$ or starting to check for monotonicity in the first formulation at $n=1$. This gives

$$\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^4}{24}\le 1-\cos(x)\le \frac{x^2}2$$

for $x^2<12$.

---

To get the strict inequalities, use the Taylor polynomials with 4 and 5 terms to bound the ones with 2 and 3 terms away from $\cos x$.